# @Published var in a nested ObservableObject changed only after second change. SwiftUI bug?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I put `Store1:ObservableObject` into `GlobalStore2:ObservableObject` and use `field1` and `field2` in `MultiStoresDemo2:View`.
I type `A` character in `field1`, `field2` doesn't redraw in `View`.
I type `B` character in `field1`, `field2` shows `A` character only.

Is this SwiftUI bug?

I wrote a little code to demo how to reproduce it.

```
final class GlobalStore2: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = GlobalStore2()

    @Published var store1 = Store1()
}

final class Store1: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = Store1()
    @Published var field1 = "" {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                self.field2 = self.field1
            }
        }
    }
    @Published var field2 = ""
}

struct MultiStoresDemo2: View {
    @ObservedObject var store = GlobalStore2.shared

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("field1", text: $store.store1.field1)
            Text("field2 \(store.store1.field2)")
        }
    }
}
```

If I change my code like below it will work

```swift
struct MultiStoresDemo2: View {
    @ObservedObject var store1 = Store1.shared
...
            Text("field2 \(Store1.shared.field2)")
            Text("field2 \(store1.field2)")
...
}
```

Comment: I don't ask why do you do that (I would not), but seems due to `.asyncAfter` it is out of view refresh flow, because with just `.async` it works as well as when not postponed at all.

Comment: @Asperi if you move field1 to GlobalStore2 my code will work. I made this little demo to explain the problem that I faced on my project.

Comment: When I tried to divide the large global store into several parts. I put async instead of code when I called server API